# Google Calendar php api 404 error not found after log in and trying to show events

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

This is the error message I'm getting:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Google\Service\Exception: { "error": { "errors":
> [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "notFound", "message": "Not Found" }
> ], "code": 404, "message": "Not Found" } } in
> /var/www/html/calendar/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Http/REST.php:134
> Stack trace: #0
> /var/www/html/calendar/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Http/REST.php(107):
> Google\Http\REST::decodeHttpResponse() #1 [internal function]:
> Google\Http\REST::doExecute() #2
> /var/www/html/calendar/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Task/Runner.php(187):
> call_user_func_array() #3
> /var/www/html/calendar/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Http/REST.php(66):
> Google\Task\Runner->run() #4
> /var/www/html/calendar/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Client.php(921):
> Google\Http\REST::execute() #5
> /var/www/html/calendar/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Service/Resource.php(238):
> Google\Client->execute() #6
> /var/www/html/calendar/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src/Calendar/Resource/Events.php(287):
> Google\Service\Resource->call() #7
> /var/www/html/calendar/index.php(20):
> Google\Service\Calendar\Resource\Events->listEvents() #8 {main} thrown
> in /var/www/html/calendar/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Http/REST.php on
> line 134

And the following are the login.php and index.php files:

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    use Google\Client;
    use Google\Service\Calendar;

    // Configura il client Google
    $client = new Client();
    $client->setDeveloperKey("*******");
    $client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/credentials.json');
    $client->addScope(Calendar::CALENDAR_EVENTS);

    // Imposta il percorso per salvare il token
    $tokenPath = __DIR__ . '/token.json';

    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
        // Ottieni il "code" dall'URL
        $code = $_GET['code'];

        // Scambia il "code" con un token di accesso e un token di aggiornamento
        $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($code);

        // Salva il token di accesso nel file
        file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($accessToken));
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit;
    } elseif (!$client->getAccessToken() || $client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        // Genera l'URL di autorizzazione
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();

        // Reindirizza l'utente a questa URL per autorizzare l'app
        header("Location: $authUrl");
        exit;
    } elseif (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    }
?>

<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    use Google\Client;
    use Google\Service\Calendar;

    // Configura il client Google
    $client = new Client();
    $client->setDeveloperKey("*******");
    $client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/credentials.json');
    $client->addScope(Calendar::CALENDAR_EVENTS);
    // Crea il servizio Google Calendar
    $service = new Calendar($client);

    // Ottieni eventi dal calendario primario
    $calendarId = 'primary';
    $events = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId);

    // Elabora gli eventi ottenuti
    if (count($events->getItems()) > 0) {
        foreach ($events->getItems() as $event) {
            echo 'Evento: ' . $event->getSummary() . '<br>';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Nessun evento trovato.';
    }
?>
```

How can I possibly fix this issue?